# Force download using inert in hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

In Hapijs v17, How to force download a file? I'm using [Inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) to handles static files and directory.

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/uploads/{file*}',
        handler: (req, h) => {
            return h.file(`./uploads/${req.params.file}`)
            .header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            .header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.file)
        },
        options: {
            auth: false
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom inert path [options](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#hfilepath-options), use **mode**: 'attachment' and **filename** properties.

Just try this it will force the user to download the file and *req.params.file* will be assigned as a file name.

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/uploads/{file*}',
        handler: (req, h) => {           
             return h.file(`./uploads/${req.params.file}`, {
                mode: 'attachment',
                filename: req.params.file
            });
        },
        options: {
            auth: false
        }
});
```